# What determines bv_len inside BIO structure (for I/O request)?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I built a ram based virtual block device driver with blk-mq API that uses `none` for I/O scheduler. I am running `fio` to perform random read/write on the device and noticed that the `bv_len` in each `bio` request is always `1024` bytes. I am not aware any place in code that sets this value explicitly. The file system is `ext4`.

Is this a default config or something I could change in code?

Comment: What is the block size of your filesystem?

Comment: @stark The value I got from the virtual device `blockdev --getbsz /dev/virt_block_dev` is 4096 bytes.

Comment: That's not the filesystem block size. Use tune2fs

Comment: Could you put the full fio command that you ran?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not aware any place in code that sets this [`bv_len`] value explicitly.

In a 5.7 kernel isn't it set explicitly in [`__bio_add_pc_page__bio_add_pc_page()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/block/bio.c#L819) and [`__bio_add_page()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/block/bio.c#L891) (which are within `block/bio.c`)? You'll have to trace back through callers to see how the passed `len` was set though.

(I found this by [searching for the `bv_len` identifier in LXR](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/C/ident/bv_len) and then going through results)

However, [@stark's comment about tune2fs is the key to any answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62684233/what-determines-bv-len-inside-bio-structure-for-i-o-request/62808949#comment110949728_62684233). You never told us the filesystem block size and if your block device is "small" it's likely your filesystem is also small and by default the choice of block size is dependent on that. If you read the [mke2fs man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4) you will see it says the following:

> **-b** *block-size*
>
> Specify the size of blocks in bytes. Valid block-size values are 1024, 2048 and 4096 bytes per block. If omitted, block-size is heuristically determined by the filesystem size and the expected usage of the filesystem (see the **-T** option).
>
> [...]
>
> **-T** *usage-type[,...]*
>
> [...]
>
> If this option is is not specified, **mke2fs** will pick a single default usage type based on the size of the filesystem to be created. If the filesystem size is less than or equal to 3 megabytes, **mke2fs** will use the filesystem type floppy. [...]

And if you look in the [default `mke2fs.conf`](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/8fd92e9af006da392d667775b8bbe0db9e8639d2/tests/mke2fs.conf.in#L26) the blocksize for a floppy is 1024.